# Using multiple setIntervals() on the same page, with the same interval, can it be error prone?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, setinterval

I have a page that has a tendency to freeze up, and I'm not able to get the problem to appear on demand, just happens intermittently. The page itself is composed of three partial views. Each partial view updates its content with a AJAX refresh and they all do so with the same 15 second interval. This works most of the time, but once in a while the page freezes up.

Before I make radical changes which are hard to test anyway, is it possible that this might be the cause? If so, what is the best way to alleviate the problem? I have thought about using different intervals, but they will collide eventually.

I was thinking about creating one setInterval function which calls functions that are responsible for one AJAX refresh each, could that work? Again, I would just test this myself, but the problem really only comes up in production, when there are many concurrent users.

Thanks in advance.

P.s. the back-end is in Ruby.

Comment: Multiple `setInterval()` calls on the same page should be fine. Is the Ajax code in question standard asynchronous Ajax? (Because if you've got synchronous Ajax that could explain the problem, especially if it only occurs when there are many concurrent users.)

Comment: even though you have 3 intervals with the same interval timings, at any given point of time only 1 can get executed because of the single threaded nature of browser...

Comment: 1. Yes it is asynchronous, I'm using $.getJSON() which can't be configured to use synchronous if I understand it correctly.
2. That's very interesting and might explain why 1 in about every 100 times the AJAX fails and doesn't retrieve the latest data. This supports my idea of having a single setInterval that calls each of the other ones right?
3. None of them call clearInterval as I don't want the refresh to stop.